# Google показывает <title> задом наперед

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, google-search

Всем привет, прошу помощи.

Гугл отображает title в результате поиска задом наперед. При чем, видит проиндексированную страницу правильно.

Исходник:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">

<meta charset='utf-8'>
<title>Массаж Позняки, Осокорки | Студия массажа Виолетты Зеленской</title>
<link rel="canonical" href="https://vio-lett.com.ua" />

<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="ru_RU" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://vio-lett.com.ua" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Массаж Позняки, Осокорки | Студия массажа Виолетты Зеленской" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Студия массажа на Позняках. 15 видов массажа. Больше 30 техник выполнения массажа. Массажисты с опытом не менее 3 года. Профессиональный массаж в Киеве. " />
<meta property="og:image" content="/img/logo.png" />
<meta name="description" content="Студия массажа на Позняках. 15 видов массажа. Больше 30 техник выполнения массажа. Массажисты с опытом не менее 3 года. Профессиональный массаж в Киеве. " />
<meta name="keywords" content="массаж Позняки, массаж на Позняках, массаж спины позняки, антицеллюлитный массаж позняки, общий массаж позняки, массаж Виолетта, Виолетта Зеленская, массаж Зеленская, массаж киев, массаж в киеве, массаж для женщин, массаж для девушек киев, массаж осокорки">

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-57x57.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-60x60.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-72x72.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-76x76.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-120x120.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-152x152.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-180x180.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192" href="/img/favicon/android-icon-192x192.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/img/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/img/favicon/favicon-96x96.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/img/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/img/favicon/manifest.json">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
<meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/img/favicon/ms-icon-144x144.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-119404055-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-119404055-1');
</script>
</head>
```

Скрин с консоли google

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это выглядит с поиска:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весь head шаблонно сделан на всех странницах и отображается корректно, главная страница почему-то исключение. Распределитель "|" по воле гугла заменился на ":".

Страница в последний раз индексировалась сегодня утром. Такие правки как description применяются в результате поиска нормально. Tile как не меняй, он всегда перевернут.

Код шаблона:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru"> 
<head>
  <!--CDN and bootstrap-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css">
  <!--meta-->
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <title><?=$title?></title>
  <link rel="canonical" href="<?=$page?>"/>
  <!--facebook-->
  <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
  <meta property="og:locale" content="ru_RU" />
  <meta property="og:url"           content="<?=$page?>" />
  <meta property="og:type"          content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title"         content="<?=$title?>" />
  <meta property="og:description"   content="<?=$description?>" />
  <meta property="og:image"         content="<?=$image?>" />
  <meta name="description" content="<?=$description?>"/>
  <meta name="keywords" content="<?=$keys?>">
  <!--favicon-->
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-57x57.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-60x60.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-72x72.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-76x76.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-114x114.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-120x120.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-144x144.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-152x152.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/img/favicon/apple-icon-180x180.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="192x192"  href="/img/favicon/android-icon-192x192.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/img/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="/img/favicon/favicon-96x96.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/img/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
  <link rel="manifest" href="/img/favicon/manifest.json">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#ffffff">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/img/favicon/ms-icon-144x144.png">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-119404055-1"></script>
  <script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-119404055-1');
</script>
</head>
```

Что не так в шаблоне? Или гугл шалит и выводит title как ему захочется?

Comment: Похоже, что гугл считает вторую часть title важнее первой и поэтому меняет вывод. Можете ознакомится с вот этой статьей https://www.sistrix.com/ask-sistrix/google-automatically-replaces-the-page-title-what-can-i-do/

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле Гугл может и не брать значение из title. Поисковик может сформировать сниппет по индексированным словам на странице. Какие у вас на странице заголовки H1, H2?

Answer (score 0):

Отображается в ответе Google не тайтл, а заголовок сниппета. Часто заголовок формируется из тега `<title>`, но по некоторым запросам он может генерироваться из контента страницы.

- Ответ - в данном примере Google выводит не тайтл, заголовок сниппета,
  который генерируется Google.